# Standalone Token Registration

Tags: opayo

Sending a request using the Test URL for Standalone Token Registration, I am faced with an internal server error with no indication as to what the problem is.

> HTTP Status Code: 500:
>
> HTTP Status Message: The request was
> unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.

The Test URL I'm POSTing to is:

https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/token.vsp

And the POST parameters are as follows:

- VPSProtocol = 3.00
- TxType = TOKEN
- Vendor = MyVendor
- VendorTxCode = UniqueVenderTxCode
- Currency = GBP
- NotificationURL = Publicly facing url

I can confirm that the Vendor is correct because I can successfully POST to the "Part of a Transaction Token Registration" URL, which returns a `NextURL` that I use to display the payment portal/entry.

I'm sending all of the required POST parameters, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:** It was me being silly. I neglected to check the response from the `HttpWebRequest` (You'd think this would be my first port of call). It turns out that the vendor I'm using doesn't currently support a `TxType` of TOKEN. I'll have to contact SagePay support in order to get this enabled.

Comment: This looks pretty reasonable. What exactly is the string you are posting (without the secure details of course)?

Comment: Hi David, The string is VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=TOKEN&Vendor=myvendor&VendorTxCode=4digitcode&Currency=GBP&NotificationURL=publiclyfacingurl

Comment: Those parameters should go in the body, not as part of the URL, that's why it's a POST and not a GET operation.

Comment: Hi David, the addition of the URL parameters was a mistake. The parameters are being sent as part of a `HttpWebRequest`. The post data string is converted to a byte array and written using a request stream.

Comment: Well this looks fine then, it could be that SagePay is broken - I have experienced that several times as they don't really seem to take care of the test environment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input David. I'll probably try again later. I've contacted support and I'm waiting to see what they say.